# After install of Laravel in Ubuntu on enter command php artisan ser failed to open stream:

Tags: laravel

php artisan ser PHP Warning: require(/home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/artisan on line 18 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/artisan on line 18

Comment: try comparing your project with [laravel Github](https://github.com/laravel/laravel)

Comment: Try `composer install` inside your project root directory.